# Why is jQuery not working in the browser action popup of a google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I've created a button whose function is to hide itself when clicked. But, it isn't working.Here's the code :

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="b">HIDE</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#b").click(function(){
$("#b").hide();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</head>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: [Works for me: JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/89ewe/).

Answer (score 3):

That [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/vysEf/), but I'd strongly suggest you research the HTML for a valid document, i.e. `</head>` must appear before `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what alex said, it's possible that Chrome is blocking your request to the CDN-hosted jQuery. You can either give that domain valid permissions in `manifest.json` or simply download the copy of jQuery and store it locally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSL for your site, then you should serve your javascript/js file via https, else chrome will block it and causing your site's feature that is using that script not working.

I noticed that you are using `http` to call jquery from google cdn. May be it is causing that problem.